# Cucumber Scenario: getSourceTagNames() inconsistently returns list in random order

Tags: java, selenium, cucumber, qaf

I am trying to implement an automated evidence capture system for each cucumber scenario that is executed. As part of that I need to use the first scenario @tag as part of the evidence folder name.

However, I have found that the getSourceTagNames() method on a cucumber scenario returns the list in a random order, compared to the order in which the tags were written. So simply calling scenario.getSourceTagNames().get(0) will not consistently give me the tag I need.

e.g
Scenario: Example
@tagINeed @secondTag @thirdTag

getSourceTagNames() may return {@thirdTag, @tagINeed, @secondTag}

Is there a way to ensure the list returned is in the same order as the order in which it was written?

Comment: Perhaps start the tag with a common prefix `@Evidence-LTM15`?

Comment: Unfortunately in the context of the automation framework, that is not a viable solution

Comment: @DanielPhillips How about mentioning it in the scenario description instead? Use some special character for parsing purposes. Use scenario.getName() to access it. Though this would be printed out in any report that might output the description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for can be achieved using [gherkin with qaf](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/latest/gherkin_client.html), you will be able to access tags in order they defined for example:

```
@tagINeed @secondTag @thirdTag
Scenario: Example
```

Java code:

```java
scenario.getGroups()[0];//will return "@tagINeed"
```

If you will use [BDD2 syntax](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/latest/bdd-syntax.html) instead of gherkin, you can have [meta-data](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/latest/scenario-meta-data.html) with scenario. For example:

```
@TestID:ABC-123
@Evidence:tagINeed @firstTag @secondTag
Scenario: Example
```

Java code:

```java
scenario.getMetaData().get("Evidence");//will return "tagINeed"
scenario.getGroups()[0];//will return "firstTag"
```